# Python pip - editable install from source that has additional local dependencies specified in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a series of plugins developed as Python eggs which reside in a subversion repository with the following directory structure:

```
├───project1
│   ├───app_plugin
│   │       setup.py
│   │
│   ├───plugin1
│   │   │   setup.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───python
│   │       │   __init__.py
│   │       │
│   │       └───package
│   │               code.py
│   │               __init__.py
│   │
│   └───plugin2
└───project2
    └───plugin3
```

I then have an active virutalenv and want to use pip to perform an editable install of the app_plugin and it's dependencies (`plugin1`, `plugin2`, `plugin3`) from source into the virtualenv's site-packages.

If it was just the `app_plugin` egg to be installed and if it only had dependencies available on PyPI, I could use this pip command:

```
pip install -e project1/app_plugin
```

However because the dependencies are local source directories and aren't packages uploaded to PyPI, pip can't locate them.

The dependencies would be easy to individually install/develop using setuptools but there are hundreds of them and I need their dependencies solved recursively and to be able continue developing them just like the main app plugin.

Previously (before pip existed) we had a script which took the main application egg's dependencies and installed them using `setup.py develop` which is what `pip -e` is supposed to do but just for a single egg.

Can pip be used to do this, resolving dependencies locally as well as any dependencies from PyPI?

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider using python wheels ([the new python packaging standard](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) instead of eggs then, if I understand your problem correctly, it can be done in quite a straightforward way.

Step 1) Compile each plugin and your app as wheels

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Step 2) Create a wheelhouse directory with all your wheels

Step 3) Install your app from the cached wheels in your virtualenv

```
pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheelhouse app_plugin
```

For more information see:
[Usage of cached wheels](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage) and a [wheelhouse package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wheelhouse) (this wheelhouse package is not neccessary and I haven't tried it but could be helpful).

Note: This is not a direct solution to your problem but is a solution that can be automated and I believe solves the underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks @benj. Will all my sdists, installed as wheels, still be editable?

Comment: @afunkyrobot, pip wheel mentions an editable install mode under options (https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel/#id7). But I'm not sure if this applies to the wheelhouse directory. I missed the "editable" bit in your title.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to consider just writing a bash script to install all your dependencies one by one by searching a directory. Not an ideal workaround.